# uniform converging functions

Tags: convergence-divergence

If I know that $\sum_M^\infty v(x)$ converges towards $f$, then $$\left| \left( f + \sum_{1}^{M-1} v(x) \right) - \sum_{1}^N v(x)\, \right| = \left|\;f - \sum_{M}^N v(x)\,\right| < \epsilon$$ for large enough $N$, and so our general series converges towards $f + $ the terms from 1 to $M-1$.

What is wrong with this proof? It is not mentioned in the book, and they instead opt for a more complicated strategy, leading me to think something is fishy about above.

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to prove here. Are you trying to show that, if we have $M$ such that $\sum_M^n v(x) \to f(x)$ uniformly as $n \to \infty$, then $\sum_1^n v(x) \to f(x) + \sum_1^{M-1} v(x)$ uniformly as $n \to \infty$?

Comment: Yes, precisely. Is that true?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your proof.